# Dll Unable to use in my project keep getting error upon referencing them

Tags: c#, wpf, webview2

Just created a small little console project however when trying to reference the dll Thye don't want to be playing along. I created a lib folder with the dll in. However when i right click and want to add reference i get project reference instead. Either way when i click on that and go into browse and select the dll i keep getting this error message:
[image]

any suggestions on this?

Comment: Is the DLL a managed assembly (i.e. .NET) or is it native code? You can't reference native code.